# iterating over dictionary values and writing into csv files: Python 3.6

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

Trying to write contents of a dictionary into a .csv file. The dictionary values are tuples. I want each row to contain a key and then iterate over the values and write each in a separate field in the same row:

I wrote this function (where v is a tuple):

```
def csv_writer(dict, filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:   
        w = csv.writer(f)
        for k,v in dict.items():
            w.writerow([k, v])
```

the contents of v appear as a tuple in the csv file, but I want to get something like this:

```
k1  v1 v2 v3 v4
k2  v1 v5 v6
```

etc.

Thanks for any tips in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `*v`, also called `splat`. More info in docs:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: Yes! Thanks! I completely forgot about the * !

Comment: @Bondrak if you believe it solved the problem, mark it as solved

Answer (score 1):

```
def csv_writer(dict, filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:   
        outfile = csv.writer(f)
        for k,v in dict.items():
            outfile.writerow([k] + v)
```

Comment: @Bondrak: `[k]+v` __is__ only one argument

Comment: Yes, true. I thought you had a comma originally, ( [k],v). Sorry. But v is a tuple, not a list, so I guess something like this could work?  w.writerow([k]+list(v))